# Make IBOutlet/IBAction Connection without mouse in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode

How to make IBOutlet/IBAction Connection without mouse in Interface Builder in XCode? Sometimes my mouse is stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Builder is designed to work with a pointing device. So you must use a mouse or any other pointing device(e.g. trackpad). Without any pointing device creating connection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need either your track pad / mouse working to work with Interface Builder.